# Does dharma only apply in India?

Tags: gods, dharma, adharma

Did Krishna make dharma only in India? If so, why not everywhere? Why wouldn't God help everyone instead of specific countries?

Why isn't India doing better since Krishna came?

Comment: You should try to know what 'Dharma' is and you'll get your answer for sure. Also, as of now, the last part of the question is unclear IMO.

Comment: i don't recall posting this..

Comment: You posted this question yesterday. It's written in the interface.

Comment: i was drunk and had a blackout...:(